# Unable to change directory via concurrently in npm script

Tags: node.js, npm-scripts

I have a website and couple of external modules added as local node dependencies (using `"file:..."`).

To update the external module references in my website, I am using npm scripts like below:

```
"scripts": {
    "preupdate-own-deps":"concurrently \"cd ../my-ext-module1 && gulp build\" \"cd ../my-ext-module2 && gulp build\"",
    "update-own-deps": "rimraf node_modules/my-ext-* && npm install --save"
}
```

Whenever I run `concurrently "cd ../my-ext-module1 && gulp build" "cd ../my-ext-module2 && gulp build"` in terminal everything is fine. But whenever the same is run using `npm run update-own-deps`, the `preupdate-own-deps` exits with following error:

```
[0] The system cannot find the path specified.
[1] The system cannot find the path specified.
[1] cd ../my-ext-module2 && gulp build exited with code 1
[0] cd ../my-ext-module1 && gulp build exited with code 1
```

As I am new to npm scripts, I am not sure what am I missing here. Please suggest.

**Update:** Stupid me, was using an old version of concurrently. Updating sorted the issue.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you're not in the directory that you think you are. Try changing this:

```
"scripts": {
    "preupdate-own-deps":"concurrently \"cd ../my-ext-module1 && gulp build\" \"cd ../my-ext-module2 && gulp build\"",
    "update-own-deps": "rimraf node_modules/my-ext-* && npm install --save"
}
```

to:

```
"scripts": {
    "preupdate-own-deps":"pwd && concurrently \"pwd && cd ../my-ext-module1 && gulp build\" \"cd ../my-ext-module2 && gulp build\"",
    "update-own-deps": "rimraf node_modules/my-ext-* && npm install --save"
}
```

to see what is the current working directory when this script is being run, and then change the `cd` command accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was using an old version of concurrently, updating the same sorted the issue. And yes, the old version was not looking at correct directory.

Comment: Adding for posterity: My issue was my command used semicolon instead of ampersand. So after changing "cd ../foo; yarn start" to "cd ../foo && yarn start", it started working.